# Moving user to a specific Group n months after membership

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, organic-groups, group-membership

Following is the use case I have to complete:

User registers on a drupal site and the admin assigns him/her to a Group (Amateur Group). Say after 6 months of registration to that Group, user has to be moved to another group (Expert Group), removing him/her from the previous group, automatically without the admin intervening.

Any ideas how this can be achieved? Is there any module for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple drupal module implementing [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to check certain conditions every time the cron is executed. You could also use [user login hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7). You just need to get all users using [entity_load('user')](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7) and check which of them have certain role (Amateur):

```
if (in_array('amateur', $user->roles) && moreThanSixMonthMembership($user)) {
  // Change roles
}
```

Once you know which users should change their group, assign the proper roles. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240596/drupal-assign-roles-in-user-save) may be helpful.

Hope it helps.